# How do I get the name of the current branch in libgit2?

Tags: libgit2

I am trying to use libgit2 to read the name of the current branch. Do I have to do some sort of resolve?

I tried using

```
git_branch_lookup
```

to look up the `git_reference` for `HEAD`, but it results in

```
Unable to find local branch 'HEAD'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Running `git branch -a` doesn't list `HEAD`. In libgit2, `HEAD` isn't considered a valid branch either. It's only a **reference**.

If you want to discover which reference is the current branch, then you should

- Load the current `HEAD` reference (try the `git_repository_head()` convenience method)
- Determine its type (using `git_reference_type()`)
- Depending on its type (`GIT_REFERENCE_SYMBOLIC` or `GIT_REFERENCE_DIRECT`) retrieve one of the following

  - The name of the branch (using `git_reference_symbolic_target()`)
  - The commit being pointed at (using `git_reference_target()`)

Comment: @Jake Was this answer helpful?

Comment: note that sometime after 0.0.17 libgit2 renamed a lot of methods, including the `git_reference_*` methods: http://librelist.com/browser//libgit2/2012/11/28/re-the-great-api-renaming-of-2012/

Comment: @Nelson Thanks. This has been fixed. Cheers ;-)

Comment: You don't have to check the reference type anymore, as `git_reference_resolve()` will "resolve" direct references and actually resolve symbolic references

Comment: @xav0989 Beware that those function serves different purposes: `git_reference_resolve` will peel the reference until a direct reference is found then return its oid. `git_reference_resolve` will accept either a direct or a symbolic reference. `git_reference_target` will only accept a direct reference. `git_reference_symbolic_target` will only accept a symbolic reference as input and return the name of the reference being pointed at (which could be a direct or another chained symbolic reference).

Comment: @nulltoken Yes. I assumed that the oid of the commit eventually associated with this reference was the end goal, but if the next target is the end goal, the `git_reference-*target` functions are better suited.

Comment: The old constant names have been updated since [v0.28.2](https://libgit2.org/libgit2/#HEAD/group/reference/git_reference_type). I went ahead and changed the constant names in this answer to the new ones.

Answer (score 1):

There is an example for this at https://libgit2.org/libgit2/ex/HEAD/status.html . It is based around the method `get_reference_shorthand`. This should give the branch name instead of the reference, so no string manipulation needed, and it should also work in the edge case where branch and remote have different names.

```
static void show_branch(git_repository *repo, int format)
{
  int error = 0;
  const char *branch = NULL;
  git_reference *head = NULL;

  error = git_repository_head(&head, repo);

  if (error == GIT_EUNBORNBRANCH || error == GIT_ENOTFOUND)
    branch = NULL;
  else if (!error) {
    branch = git_reference_shorthand(head);
  } else
    check_lg2(error, "failed to get current branch", NULL);

  if (format == FORMAT_LONG)
    printf("# On branch %s\n",
      branch ? branch : "Not currently on any branch.");
  else
    printf("## %s\n", branch ? branch : "HEAD (no branch)");

  git_reference_free(head);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I did not find the existing answer/comments helpful, when having this exact problem.  Instead I combined `git_reference_lookup()` and `git_reference_symbolic_target()`.

```
git_reference* head_ref;
git_reference_lookup(&head_ref, repo, "HEAD");
const char *symbolic_ref;
symbolic_ref = git_reference_symbolic_target(head_ref);
std::string result;
// Skip leading "refs/heads/" -- 11 chars.
if (symbolic_ref) result = &symbolic_ref[11];
git_reference_free(head_ref);
```

This feels like something of a dirty hack, but it's the best I've managed.  The `result` string either ends up empty (e.g. detached head, there is no checked out branch) or contains the name of the checked out branch.  The symbolic target is owned by the ref, so copy that value into the string before freeing it!

Comment: In retrospect, this is almost exactly what the existing answer said, just that it also contains some (out of date?) red herrings which confused me at first.